# SWF Screenshots

Tags: flash

I have a collection of .swf files and they all have different dimensions.

How can I create screenshots of these flash movies automatically?

Would be very handy, because otherwise I will have to make screenshots manually for a few hundred flash movies.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Load each swf in your collection into flash movieclip & do the following.

If mc is the movieclip into which you loaded an flash movie:

```
BitmapData myBitmapData=new BitmapData(mc.width,mc.height,false);       
myBitmapData.draw(mc);
```

Once you have the bitmap data, you can do anything to get the image. Look at the [Adobe reference](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) to see what you can do with this bitmap data.

Also, Adobe flash player 10 now allows directly saving of bitmap files.

```
var bitmap : Bitmap = new Bitmap(myBitmapData);
var jpg:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
var ba:ByteArray = jpg.encode(bitmapData);
file.save(ba, 'ScreenShot'+ i + '.jpg'); // i is the incrementing variable in the loop
```

The above will save files as ScreenShot1.jpg, ScreenShot2.jpg....so on.

But it will ask for confirmation every time ( A limitation of flash player as of yet )

Comment: Why floodfill? Fourth argument in BitmapData constructor allows to set background color.

Comment: Used flood fill accidentally. Actually intended to show OP of clearing the BitmapData the first time. Misplaced it :)......thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

I would make AIR application. All it needs is two directories - source with swf's and destination for screenshots. Load each clip with `Loader`, take screenshot with BitmapData.draw, encode with JPEGEncoder (there is also PNGEncoder) and save to file. No confirmations, AIR can do all that automatically. Just learn `File` class and encoders.

Comment: Well I had considered suggesting AIR too, but since the OP tagged it as flash... anyways, nice.